# Using videojs with youtube.js

Tags: javascript, youtube, video.js

Im using the videojs(http://videojs.com/) Plugin in combination with youtube.js(https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) to play youtube videos in a custom player.

In the head im loading the css from video.js and this is the html body

```
<div id="am-youtube-container" class="row collapse">
   <video
     id="vid1"
     class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
     controls
     autoplay
     width="640" height="264"
     data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
   >
   </video>
   <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.min.js"/>
   <script src="path to youtubejs/Youtube.js"/>
</div>
```

I always get the following error :

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: The "Youtube" tech is undefined. Skipped browser support check for that tech.
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this video.
```

Im unable to find a solution for this.When im using the example from youtube.js it works with the exact same code.

Comment: There are a few answers on github so you could check there.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. It seems that video.js 5.0 causes some troubles.  I had to add the script in the head and I added this.initYTPlayer(); to the setTimeout inside the constructor.

Comment: hey @Kbi , make sure you have right path to your youtube.js

Answer (score 0):

Get the youtube.js by bower:

```
bower install videojs-youtube
```

Then you will have both video.min.js and Youtube.min.js in folder bower_component like this :

Copy paste this as html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="am-youtube-container" class="row collapse">
   <video
     id="vid1"
     class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
     controls
     autoplay
     width="640" height="264"
     data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
   >
   </video>
   <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.min.js"/>
   <script src="path to youtubejs/Youtube.js"/>
</div>

  <script src="bower_components/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/videojs-youtube/dist/Youtube.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have tried and the solution is replacing :

```
   <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.min.js"/>
```

with this:

```
  <script src="bower_components/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place under your code, where you build your youtube a variable:

```
const youtube = require('videojs-youtube');
```

And also the require for your "videojs" e.g.

```
const videojs = require('video.js');
_player = videojs('#video-js');
```